# Opening .tgz files in C

Tags: c, buffer, tar, filereader

I'm trying to copy a .tgz file into memory and sending it elsewhere.

Using fopen I get a NULL pointer which tells me that a .tgz file isn't a binary file, but I was wondering if it is even possible to open, buffer, and pass a .tgz file using C standard libraries and  libraries?

Comment: Try calling `perror("fopen");` when you determine that `fopen` returns null.

Comment: if a plain fopen fails for any file, you're doing something wrong, fopen() should open all types of files.

Comment: You're probably passing the wrong filename to fopen. Common mistakes include: 1. forgetting to remove the newline after reading a filename from a text file; 2. using backslashes as path separators and forgetting to double them inside a C string; 3. using a filename you got from readdir without prepending the directory or chdir'ing into it.

Comment: @AlanCurry, that was exactly it. I keep forgetting DOS doesn't let you have file names > 7 or 8 characters, not the first time it has screwed me over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: I was wondering if it is even possible to open, buffer, and pass a
>   .tgz file using C standard libraries and libraries?

Q: Do you want to copy the binary .tgz file as-is?  Sure - piece of cake :)

Or do you want to *interpret* the .tgz file, and then copy its *contents*?

If the latter, I'd look at "zlib":

- http://www.gzip.org/

> Q: Using fopen I get a NULL pointer which tells me that a .tgz file
>   isn't a binary file

A: That tells you no such thing!  You should be able to "fopen()" *any* file ... as long as it exists, and as long as you have the correct permissions.

Use "perror()" to find out what the underlying error was.

Comment: see my comment to Alan Curry, I will accept this answer because it was my own goof. Upvoted for now.